# PHP putting an array within an array using variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm just wondering, is this correct? I can't find any guide for doing it this way, but I don't know how many elements regIds will have, so it seems like it needs to be done like this. regIds is the array.

```
$fields = array(
       'registration_ids' => $regIds,
         'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
        );
```

Edit: full script with sensitive values omitted:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

$url = "dburl";
$username = "dbusername";
$password = "password";
$db = "database";
mysql_connect($url, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db);
$sql = mysql_query("select chatId from Players natural join Accounts where account_state = 'O' and ABS(playerLat - '$latitude') < 0.1 and ABS(playerLong - '$longitude') < 0.1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $regIds[] = $row;
}

mysql_close();

$apiKey = "key";    

// Set POST variables
$urls = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields = array(
           'registration_ids' => $regIds,
             'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
            );
$headers = array(
          'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
         'Content-Type: application/json'
          );

//Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urls );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

//Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

It doesn't return anything

Comment: That's certainly valid PHP, if that's what you're asking. If you would rather have `$regIds` merged into the `$fields` array, you can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: I think it needs to be like this to use google cloud messaging. Something isn't working, I thought this could be the issue. I'll look elsewhere in the code then, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your SQL works? Usually with Joins, you'd need to add the table id like `SELECT table1.col1, table2.col1 FROM table1 JOIN table2 ...`. See docs, [Mysql Select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) or [column alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything's OK except that the server host blocked some curl functions.

Answer (score 0):

That's one way to do it.

When using array_merge, you would lose the $regIds indexes:

```
$regIds = array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
$fields = array( 'data' => array( 'message' => $message );
$fields = array_merge( $fields, $regIds );
// How do you know where the $regIds values start? In this case, we know
// they start at 1 (index 0 is the 'data' array)
$fields[index] // Expecting index to be an item on $regIds
```

While your way is more useful (IMHO):

```
echo $fields['registration_ids'][0]; // Result: 1
```

Hope it helps :P.

Comment: Well it's being sent to the google cloud messaging server, so it's supposed to be in a particular format. I'll update the original answer with the complete script.

Comment: Well, in that case, the documentation says that it must be an array of at least 1 string (with the ID) and up to 1000 IDs, so, you're doing it right -> http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#send-msg